# Tensorflow construct tensor of shape (N*N*K) based on unknown batch size N

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to build a custom loss function that needs to use the unknown batch size to construct more tensors.

The batch size is a "dynamic" shape `?`. Assuming this is notated as `N` and the prediction tensor has a shape of `N*K` where `K` is known. How do I build a tensor with a shape of `N*N*K`?

Basically it's multiple "mask matrices" with the same shape as the prediction tensor. So if the batch size is 2, then there should be 2 mask matrices, each of which is `N*K`.

I first tried to use `tf.while_loop`, to build up a list of `N*K` matrices, and then use `tf.concat(l, axis=0)`. but this didn't work because the `tf.while_loop` either didn't run the side effects to append into `l`, or if I tried to accumulate `l` recursively, it also complained that the resulting shape was different from the `loop_vars`.

Situation is for TF1, but would be interesting a solution in TF2.

---

Here's an attempt:

```
predictions_arr = np.array([
    [1,2,3,4],
    [1,2,3,4],
    [1,2,3,4]
], dtype=np.float32)

predictions = tf.constant(predictions_arr, dtype=tf.float32)

predictions_shape = tf.shape(predictions)

batch_size, feature_size = predictions_shape[0], predictions_shape[1]

def mask(i):
    zero_vector = tf.zeros((1, feature_size), dtype=tf.float32)
    one_vector = tf.ones((1, feature_size), dtype=tf.float32)
    # how do I compare j != i?
    # seems like it is not possible
    # also the dtypes don't work
    mask_matrix = tf.map_fn(
        lambda j: one_vector if j != i else zero_vector,
        tf.range(batch_size, dtype=tf.float32)
    )
    return mask_matrix

mask(0)
```

This gives me: `ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype float32 for Tensor with dtype int32: <tf.Tensor 'strided_slice:0' shape=() dtype=int32>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`tf.shape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/shape) to get a dynamic shape and variables corresponding to dynamic shape values. Specifically you want to do something like this:

```
shape = tf.shape(predictions)
n, k = shape[0], shape[1]
#  n, k = shape might not work if TF can't figure out the dimension in advance
result = tf.zeros([n, n, k])
```

EDIT: Following the comments, here's a complete snippet that seems to work (tested in TF 2)

```
@tf.function
def my_loss_matrix(predictions, i):
  """Generate the i-th loss matrix"""
  shape = tf.shape(predictions)
  n, k = shape[0], shape[1]
  return tf.ones([n, k]) * i


@tf.function
def my_loss(predictions):
  shape = tf.shape(predictions)
  n, k = shape[0], shape[1]
  return tf.map_fn(lambda i: my_loss_matrix(predictions, i), tf.range(n, dtype=predictions.dtype))

predictions = tf.Variable(tf.ones([10,3]))
my_loss(predictions)
```

Comment: Also, note that I didn't use TF 2 (had the luck of graduating university before it came out :)) so I hope it should still work with TF 2 and not just with TF 1.

Comment: In this case we get a `?, ?, ?` as the shape of the result. Is this desirable since the `k` is actually known, just by `predictions.shape[1]`.

Comment: Also this doesn't appear to be assignable. That is I have another function that is meant to compute each mask (`N*K`), and each mask has different values.

Comment: Added a snippet which I just ran with TF 2 (had an excuse to read the migration guide, thanks :))

Comment: @CMCDragonkai - Added an example showing how to generate a matrix for each value

Comment: I'm getting this unfortunately: `ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype float32 for Tensor with dtype int32: <tf.Tensor 'strided_slice:0' shape=() dtype=int32>`. It's due to the `tf.range` dtype. If I switch that to `int32`, it then complains that is incorrect. I'm in TF1.15.

Comment: So I found that if everything is `int32` it works. But my prediction data is actually `float32` and has to stay as `float32`.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai - Make sure you cast all values upon creating them (the zeros, ones, range, etc.) to the dtype of the predictions and it should be fine.

Comment: One of the problems I have, if you see my edited question is also that I use `!=` to compare the index. But I realized this is not possible, because the index is a slice of `tf.range`. I'm trying to create a condition that creates a mask based on whether the index equals the current number.

Comment: Oh I was missing the `out_type` for `tf.shape`.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai - Note that you cannot compare values like that, as `if` resolve by python values and what you really want is to resolve by the dynamic value of the placeholder. Prefer `tf.cond` for that

Comment: I found the to use `tf.cond` in `f = lambda j: tf.cond(tf.not_equal(j, i), lambda: one_vector, lambda: zero_vector)`.

Comment: But the resulting shape is `N*1*K`. I can squeeze this, but eventually I need to call `mask(...)`, one for each row in the predictions matrix.

Comment: Turns out I didn't need to squeeze it, just remove the `1` from `zero_vector` and `one_vector` shapes.